# Django.Резервное копирование и бэкап

Tags: django, sqlite, резервное-копирование

Доброго времени суток. У меня задание сделать сервер обработки запросов с использованием `Django`.
Для хранения клиентских данных используеться `SQLite`.
В задании такой пункт:

> - Резервное хранение и бэкапы раз в неделю для того, чтобы данные не пропали

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать резервное копирование в рамках `Django` проекта, либо же резервирование лучше переложить на другие програмные средства?
Или подскажите какие пути можно выбрать для реализации данного пункта задания?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бекап можно делать вручную, для этого просто сделай архив проекта. Поскольку используется SQLite, то ничего дополнительно не потребуется.
Для автоматизации можно написать bash скрипт.

Comment: Спасибо. Я что-то такое и представлял.